# How to explain satiated preferences with algebra?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

From looking at the graphical illustrations, I understand that satiated preferences violate the monotonicity assumption. I was wondering if there is algebra which can be used to show this?

Comment: There are several monotonicity assumptions. Which one do you have in mind?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I am not sure sorry I have just learnt about this topic and know that we assume more is always preferred to less. But this isn't the case for satiated preferences and I'm wondering if there is a numerical example that can show this?

Answer (score 3):

As you can tell from the comments, there are multiple versions of monotonicity in preference theory, but let us assume the (in my opinion) most intuitive one for now, and say

A preference $\succeq$ represented by utility function $u(\cdot)$ is **strictly monotonic** if whenever $x > y$, $u(x) > u(y)$

Let us consider the most degenerate satiated preference over $\mathbb{R}$,
$$
 u(x) = 5 \quad \text{ for any }  x 
$$
(why 5? because why not).

Consider $348050348509485$ and $0$.

It is quite clear that $348050348509485 > 0$.

However, $u(348050348509485) = 5 = u(0)$.

This preference fails the strict monotoncitiy assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to think about it:

Assume your preferences are differentiable, U = f(x).
If your preferences are monotonically increasing, meaning:

- $U_1 = f(x)$
- $U_2 = f(x+e)$
- $U_2 > U_1; e > 0$

Then the first derivative is always positive, since a derivative is:
$\lim\limits_{e \to 0} \frac{f(x+e)-f(x)}{e}$

If a first derivative is positive, the agent prefers more.
Since the this is true everywhere, the agent always prefers more, they are *insatiable*.

Answer (score 2):

Satiation means there is a consumption bundle that is at least as good as any other consumption bundle. Monotonicity means that larger bundles are always better. Since there is always a larger bundle, no bundle can be at least as good as any other consumption bundle when preferences are monotone. So monotone preferences are never satiated.